# My update query executes but doesn't update

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have this update query.

```
UPDATE production_shr_01
SET    total_hours = hours, total_weight = weight, percentage = total_hours / 7893.3
WHERE  (status = 'X')
```

The query executes fine but the problem is that when this query executes, it doesn't update the percentage field. What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us the column type for percentage?

Answer (score 5):

Either status = 'X' doesn't find any rows or (and the next is more likely) since you update total_hours in the same statement, total_hours could be 0 (or NULL) and therefor no update;
I'd suggest you use the hours field for updating like this:

```
UPDATE production_shr_01
SET    total_hours = hours, total_weight = weight, percentage = hours / 7893.3
WHERE  (status = 'X')
```

Answer (score 1):

In `percentage = total_hours / 7893.3` clause, the old value of `total_hours` will be used. `Percentage` was updated but with the old value. So it looks like it was not updated. Please use `percentage = hours/ 7893.3`